# expected primary-expression before 'unsigned' in my program (destructors and constructors problems)

Tags: c++

Hi I am new in c++ and I make skeleton of program and I have some problems with destructors and constructors.

My head.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "set_char.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main() 
{

    set_char *z1 = new set_char(unsigned char *zbior[]);
    delete z1;

    return 0;
};
```

My `set_char.hpp` class file:

```
#define ROZMIAR_MAX 256
class set_char
{
    unsigned char zbior[ROZMIAR_MAX];

    public:

        set_char(unsigned char *zbior[]);
        ~set_char(unsigned char *zbior[]);

        int nalezy(unsigned char);
        int licznosc();

        void dodaj(unsigned char);
        void usun(unsigned char);

};
```

And my `set_char.cpp` file:

```
#include "set_char.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

set_char(unsigned char *zbior[]);
~set_char(unsigned char *zbior[]);

void set_char::dodaj(unsigned char)
{

};

void set_char::usun(unsigned char)
{

};

int set_char::nalezy(unsigned char)
{   

};

int set_char::licznosc()
{

};
```

Comment: Please format your code properly (indent four spaces).

Comment: What exactly do you believe you're passing as the constructor's parameter? I would recommend that you pick up your book and read about parameters to functions and constructors. And since you're new, don't use `new`.

Comment: `new set_char(unsigned char *zbior[]);` this contains a parameter declaration, it's not a constructor call.

Answer (score 1):

Among others:

you should not add any parameters in destructors:

```
~set_char(unsigned char *zbior[]);
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ --- remove it
```

When creating set_char you should provide pointer to your array, and not the actual parameter type:

```
set_char *z1 = new set_char(unsigned char *zbior[]);
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

## 1

You did not define your `Constructor` and `Destructor`

You declared them both in your `set_char.hpp`

```
set_char(unsigned char *zbior[]);
~set_char(unsigned char *zbior[]);
```

However in `set_char.cpp` you re-declare them again without a return type. Defining a `Constructor` and `Destructor` outside of a `class` is illegal. Your compiler thinks they are `functions` and searches for a return type.

## 2

a `Destructor` may not have any arguments.

## 3

If you define an array as an argument in a `Function` or a `Constructor` or `Destructor` with brackets '[]', it may not be of variable length, thus it must be defined. If it is intended to be of variable length, it must be left out.

## 4

You are calling the constructor in a bad way using:

```
new set_char(unsigned char *zbior[]);
```

You already declared what arguments it takes, so hand it the arguments. A `null pointer`, for example.

The correct way to do it in `set_char.hpp`:

```
set_char(unsigned char *);
~set_char();
```

The correct way to do it in `set_char.cpp`:

```
set_char::set_char(unsigned char *zbior)
{
    //Your definition
}

set_char::~set_char();
{
    //Your definition
}
```

The correct way to do it in `head.cpp`:

```
set_char *z1 = new set_char(0x0);
```

Also side-note, usually using the `define` macro to define constants, is a `C` way. In `C++` it is usually done with:

```
static const size_t ROZMIAR_MAX 256;
```

Second side-note. It is considered 'neater' code if you have your constants/functions and whatnot defined inside a `namespace`